# 7x7 Golomb square

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

Can you paint $7$ cells of a $7 \times 7$ grid such that the Euclidean distance* between any pair of painted cells is distinct? Good luck!

*The Euclidean distance between cells $(r_1,c_1)$ and $(r_2,c_2)$ is $\sqrt{(r_1-r_2)^2+(c_1-c_2)^2}$.

Comment: Note I am calling it Golomb square even though such a name doesn't exist. It is related to Golomb rulers and Costas arrays, but different to them.

Comment: There is a nice integer sequence for this problem: https://oeis.org/A193838

Comment: In the sequence above I've added solutions for larger grids.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know how you would be able to deduce a solution to this, so I used a computer. It turns out that the solution is unique (ignoring rotation and reflection).

> ```
>  X . . X . . .
>  . . . . . . .
>  X X . . . . .
>  . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . X .
>  . . X . . . X
> ```

My C# program does a straightforward exhaustive search:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;

  namespace TempProg
  {
     class PSEGolombSquare
     {
        private const int N = 7; // grid size
        private const int S = 7; // number of squares

        public static void Main()
        {
           DoSearch(new int[S], 0);
        }

        private static void DoSearch(int[] coords, int nextIndex)
        {
           if (nextIndex == coords.Length)
           {
              // founf a solution
              foreach (int i in coords)
                 Console.Write("{0}{1}  ", i % N, i / N);
              Console.WriteLine();
              return;
           }
           // add another square
           int first = nextIndex == 0 ? 0 : coords[nextIndex - 1] + 1;
           for (int c = first; c < N * N; c++)
           {
              coords[nextIndex] = c;
              if (IsValid(coords, nextIndex + 1))
                 DoSearch(coords, nextIndex + 1);
           }
        }

        private static bool IsValid(int[] coords, int num)
        {
           ISet<int> distances = new SortedSet<int>();
           for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
           {
              for (int j = i+1; j < num; j++)
              {
                 int d = GetDistance(coords[i], coords[j]);
                 if (distances.Contains(d)) return false;
                 distances.Add(d);
              }
           }
           return true;
        }

        private static int GetDistance(int v1, int v2)
        {
           int dx = v1 % N - v2 % N;
           int dy = v1 / N - v2 / N;
           return dx * dx + dy * dy;
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Correct. That's the solution I have. I was surprised that it is unique only for this particular grid size. Let's see if anyone can find this by hand.

Comment: Confirmed 8 isomorphic solutions via integer linear programming.

Comment: Almost posted my by hand (other) solution; forgot about the 3-4-5 triangle  :-(

Answer (score 2):

Matt Parker hosted a challenge to solve this puzzle last year. The participants found that there were two distinct solutions for 6x6, one for 7x7, and none for 8x8 or 9x9 (up to rotations/reflections).

https://youtu.be/G0i_YSFvMb0?t=366

According to comments on the video, the search was extended with no solutions found up to 14x14, and you can prove that no solutions exist for larger grids because there are more combinations of pairs of points than there are possible distinct distances.

https://oscarcunningham.com/670/unique-distancing-problem/

Comment: Could you please provide copies of the proofs/solutions within your answer? This makes it self-contained, so people don't have to watch an external video/read an external link to find the answer. It also protects against link rot.

Comment: @bobble The solution for 7x7 is identical to the one in the accepted answer, and does not need to be repeated. The proof for large n is already included, it is the one line statement "there are more combinations of pairs of points than there are possible distinct distances".

Comment: That one line seems to me like it needs some further elaboration. The _easy_ bound is # possible distances <= about 3/4 (n-1)^2 which isn't smaller than n(n-1)/2. In the limit of large n, a famous theorem of Landau shows that there aren't enough distinct distances, but (1) it's quite nontrivial and (2) I don't know whether it gives explicit bounds that would let you show that n >= 14 is enough. Am I missing something?

Comment: (sorry, should have put @BradyGilg in that)

Comment: (I had a look at the video, and it seems like no one actually _proved_ you can't do it for n>14; they checked a bunch of specific cases and showed that the required inequality holds, and they quoted the Landau result which shows that _for large enough n_ there are no solutions, but I don't see any sign of an actual proof that has the necessary quantitative estimates.)

Comment: Landau proceeds by considering f(s) := the sum of n^-s over nonnegative integers n that are sums of two squares, and estimating partial sums of the series (which are the numbers we want) in terms of integrals involving f. I don't have a copy of the actual paper and don't know whether one can get adequate explicit bounds on the errors.

Comment: Presumably the reason you can evaluate things involving f is that there's some sort of Dirichlet-product thing -- f(s) = product (1-p^-s)^-1 product (1-q^-2s)^-1 where the first product is over primes p that are 1 mod 4 and the second is over primes q that are 3 mod 4, which will equal zeta(s) product (1+q^-s)^-1, the product again being over primes that are 3 mod 4. I don't have enough Dirichlet-series-fu for it to be obvious to me exactly what one should do next.

Comment: Er, there'll be a factor for the prime 2 as well, sorry. (1-2^-s)^-1.

Comment: wow I didn't realise this is a famous problem!

Comment: Well, the original question is YouTube-famous and the question about sums of two squares is mathematician-famous. I'm not sure either counts as _famous_-famous.

Comment: What do you mean by sums of two squares?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Where does that 3/4 (n-1)^2 come from? Doesn't one rather easily get 1/2 n(n+1)?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky If two points are separated by a distance $a$ horizontally and $b$ vertically, the square of the distance between them is $a^2+b^2$. So the number of possible distances is at most the number of sums of two squares between 1 and $(n-1)^2$. Oh, wait, I mean $2(n-1)^2$ so the details of what I wrote above are utterly wrong, but the Landau result is still enough to do the job.

Comment: @loopywalt You can rather easily get n(n+1)/2, indeed, which embarrassingly I hadn't noticed, but I don't see any obvious way to reduce that any further. Whereas the sums-of-two-squares thing lets you exploit the fact that most numbers aren't the sum of two squares.