# All distances different on a chess board

Tags: geometry, optimization

Here is a simple formulation for, I believe, a quite difficult problem.

I have played with it, I don't have the answer yet.

The question: How many pawns can you put on a standard 8x8 chess board in such a way that the distances between two pawns are all different?

Needless to say, each pawn must be exactly centered on a square of the board.

[image]

Computers are allowed.  Without it, it is quite laborious to even check the validity of a solution.

If no proof of optimality is given (answering to "how many") then my vote goes to the solution that has the most pawns on the board.

Comment: How do we count the squares that are a knight's move away (e.g. two squares down and one to the left)?

Comment: @Taco I think it is clear $\sqrt 5$

Comment: @Taco Yes, it is usualy called "Pythagorean theorem" :-)

Comment: @z100, well they're right though in that the question doesn't say which distance metric would be used. Though using something other than the usual geometric distance would probably make this relatively trivial...

Comment: This question is similar to my previous question: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109624/7x7-golomb-square

Comment: For results in larger grids see this sequence: https://oeis.org/A193838

Comment: Oh, well, OK, there is nothing new in this problem...  I hope you enjoyed it anyway.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Also [A271490](https://oeis.org/A271490)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The maximum is

> 7

> [image]

For this solution, the squared distances are

> $\{1,2,4,5,9,10,13,16,17,26,29,34,37,40,45,49,53,58,65,85,98\}$

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether a pawn is placed on square $(i,j)$.
For each pair $(i_1,j_1)$ and $(i_2,j_2)$, let binary decision variable $y_{i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2}$ indicate whether $x_{i_1,j_1} \land x_{i_2,j_2}$.
For each distance $d$, let $P_d$ be the set of pairs $(i_1,j_1)$ and $(i_2,j_2)$ such that $\sqrt{(i_1-i_2)^2+(j_1-j_2)^2}=d$.

The problem is to maximize $\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j}$ subject to
\begin{align}
x_{i_1,j_1} + x_{i_2,j_2} - 1 &\le y_{i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2} &&\text{for all pairs $(i_1,j_1)$ and $(i_2,j_2)$} \tag1\\
\sum_{(i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2) \in P_d} y_{i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2} &\le 1 &&\text{for all $d$} \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces the logical implication $x_{i_1,j_1} \land x_{i_2,j_2} \implies y_{i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2}$.
Constraint $(2)$ prevents more than one pair per distance.

Comment: Row 2 column 5 is directly next to another tile diagonally, same as row 1 columns 1 and 2. Do diagonals not count, or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: The Euclidean distances are $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Ah, okay, so it's just over my head mathematically lol got it 

Comment: That was fast!  It seems that with the right tools the problem isn't that hard after all.

Comment: You can also place this many pawns on a 7x7 board. In that case, the solution is unique up to rotation/reflection.

Comment: @DanielMathias I confirm your result.

Comment: You give the answer (a maximum and an example) and you say it can be found by restating the question as a linear programming question. But you don't show how to solve that latter question. Restating a question as another is helpful _if you solve the other_.

Comment: I used an ILP solver.

Comment: It is true, I trusted RobPratt that he didn't bluff and actually did run the solver.  But if he is wrong and someone comes up with a 8-pawn solution, I will change the accepted answer.